# Vertical align and solid row divider

Tags: html, css

I have a panel with two rows. Each row have 2 columns. What I need is to vertical align the left text (column 1) with the height of the right select (column 2).

This is what I have:

[image]

Also I don't have the default row that divide each row. I bought a template may be I have an override in some of the css files but I can't see nothing

The code for the panel is:

```
<div class="wrapper_indent">
@foreach($dias as $dia)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="form-control header-card">
            {{$dia['nombre'] }}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <span class="body-card">Primer turno</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select name="example" class="form-control selecthora"> 
                    @foreach($dia['horarios'] as $horario)
                        <option {{ ($dia['valorInicio']===$horario)?'selected="selected"':''}} value="{{$dia['valorInicio']}}">{{$horario}}</option> 
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <span class="body-card">Último turno</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select name="example" class="form-control selecthora"> 
                    @foreach($dia['horarios'] as $horario)
                        <option {{ ($dia['valorFin']===$horario)?'selected="selected"':''}} value="{{$dia['valorFin']}}">{{$horario}}</option> 
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach

</div><!-- End wrapper_indent -->
```

My custom css for trying to solve the problem is the following:

```
.body-card{
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: It is better to post the real HTML, not the server template

Comment: This is the real html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.panel .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; //for vertical-alignment
    justify-content: center; //for horizontal-alignment
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The code answe the question. Please, tell my whi it solves the problem. Thanks